# jsPDF - How can I add images in grid

Tags: javascript, printing, grid, jspdf

I am using **[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)** to create pdf file from the image collections.
I want to add images like the screenshot below so that each image can add one after another and auto-create a new pdf page if image count increases.
The purpose of this is to print the ID card on one page from existing images.

[image]

Here is the code I have tried.

```
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 204, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 325, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 204, 325, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 325 * 2, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 204, 325 * 2, imgWidth, imgHeight);

    doc.addPage();

    doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 204, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
```

So this is really hard to set an image position because the amount of the image is dynamic.

Comment: Able to solve this issue?